# Rules for concatenating a CRLF (Carriage Return, Line Feed) to a std::string

Tags: c++, string-literals, stdstring

This code below outputs

```
rm-data;
Content-Disposition: form-data;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h5z89qv6f

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n';
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    std::string b = "Content-Disposition: " + std::string("form-data;") + '\r' + '\n';
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

I expected `a` to have a CRLF concatenated, but looks like its doing pointer arithmetic by adding the ASCII values for `\r (13) + \n (10) = 23` starting offset within the text.

However, for `b`, a CRLF is correctly concatenated.

Perhaps a better way is

```
std::string a = "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + std::string("\r\n");
```

or

```
std::string a = "Content-Disposition: form-data;\r\n";
```

**Question**

Is the data type immediately preceding the CRLF determining the concatenation rules?

Comment: There are no concatenation rules, rather there are rules for which version of operator+ is being used. Those rules depend on the types of the left and right of the operator. And you are correct, the string literal + char version is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: why not `"Content-Disposition: form-data;\r\n"` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This expression:

```cpp
"Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n'
```

...in terms of types is: `<string literal> + <char> + <char>`. That isn't supported directly, so it looks for a conversion that will allow it to work, and comes up with `<char *> + <integer> + <integer>`.

Thus, we end up with a pointer into the middle (or past the end) of the string literal.

This expression:

```cpp
"Content-Disposition: " + std::string("form-data;") + '\r' + '\n'
```

...in terms of types is:

```
<string literal> + <string> + <char> + <char>
```

Again, that's done left to right, so we start with `<string literal> + <string>`. That's not supported directly but `<char *> + <string>` is, so that's what it does (producing a `<string>` result). That leads to `<string> + <char>`, which is supported directly (and again, returns a `<string>`). Then the same thing again. As you'd expect, `<string> + <char>` yields a string with that char concatenated to the end.

In *most* situations, a string literal will convert to a pointer to (`const`) `char`, so any attempt at doing addition (or similar) is going to affect the pointer, not the underlying stored data unless the other operand is something (like `std::string`) that provides an overload for `pointer to const char` (or `array of const char` of the right size).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed your first case results in pointer arithmetic. ;-)

There is no overloaded `operator+` for C-String literals. A C-String literal is just an array of constant `char`s and so pointer arithmetic applies to it.

```
operator+(
    operator+(
        char const(&)[32]
        , char
    ) -> char const*
    , char
) -> char const*
```

**Note:** `char const(&)[32]` is a reference to an array with 32 elements of constant `char`'s. You can test this with:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    decltype("Content-Disposition: form-data;"),
    char const(&)[32]
>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    decltype("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\n'),
    char const*
>);
```

In your second case is an `std::string` object involved in your first plus operation. `std::string` has an [overloaded plus operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) which is called. It returns another `std::string` object so the following plus call one of these overloads again.

```
operator+(
    operator+(
        operator+(
            char const(&)[22]
            , std::string
          ) -> std::string
        , char
    ) -> std::string
    , char
) -> std::string
```

`clang` gives you appropriate warnings about the code:

```
<source>:7:59: warning: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-int]
    std::string fieldA{ "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n'};
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:7:59: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
    std::string fieldA{ "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n'};
                                                          ^
                        &                                 [     ]
<source>:7:59: warning: adding 'char' to a string pointer does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-char]
    std::string fieldA{ "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n'};
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:7:59: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
    std::string fieldA{ "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n'};
                                                          ^
                        &                                 [     ]
<source>:7:66: warning: adding 'char' to a string pointer does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-char]
    std::string fieldA{ "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n'};
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:7:66: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
    std::string fieldA{ "Content-Disposition: form-data;" + '\r' + '\n'};
                                                                 ^
                        &                                        [     ]
3 warnings generated.
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rhTs1W777

Use [`std::string`'s user defined literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to create an `std::string` literal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals; // ""s -> std::string

    auto const c = "Content-Disposition: form-data;"s + '\r' + '\n';
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data;
```

Comment: Nice note about the `clang` warnings. gcc or the VS compilers didn't have any warnings. Thanks!